# center align image on homepage wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm kind of a noob to website development so I'm not sure how to read the massive CSS file. Basically, I want my image slider on the homepage to be centered and not toward the left side of the page. I looked at some code by the inspect tool but I couldn't figure out where to make changes to make the body aligned center only for the homepage.

My website is www.indiacanada.net

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Add `margin: 0 auto; float: none;` to `.col-md-8 .la-content-inside` element..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add class "col-md-offset-2" for the below DIV wich contains the slider.

```
<div class="col-md-8 la-content-inside col-md-offset-2">
```

And remove the below empty element.

```
<div class="col-md-4 left_sidebar"><aside id="la-right" role="complementary"></aside></div>
```

Comment: Hi, I used an image slider plugin. When I add this directly to the text field on home page, the image gets reduced. Also, I'm not able to find col-md-4 class in my style.css file.

Comment: <div class="col-md-4 left_sidebar"><aside id="la-right" role="complementary"></aside></div>
Remove this from HTML file

Comment: you are using bootstrap with 12 column layout. In which you used an 8 column space for the image slider. after this you placed an 4 column div with out any content. So first you have to remove this empty widget
<div class="col-md-4 left_sidebar"><aside id="la-right" role="complementary"></aside></div>. Once you remove this, you have to push the 8 column widget towards right by 2 column to make it center aligned. for that you need to apply the class col-md-offset-2.

Comment: Hey Pons, I've a quick question. I only want to have the shift only on the homepage. When I shift it by 2, all the other pages' content gets shifted as well. So I wrote this code in PHP, but it doesn't work. Can you give me some hints? Thanks! -----> '  <?php if (is_front_page() ) {
   echo '<div class="col-md-8 la-content-inside col-md-offset-2">';
   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  } else {
   echo '<div class="col-md-8 la-content-inside">';
   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  }
  ?>'

Comment: Sorry Ravi, I don't know php or any programming stuff.